# Excel - Concatenation without "-"

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, concatenation

Im probably over thinking this but here it goes.

So im trying to creat a user name based on a useres first inital and last name. Simple way of doing it.

Given a list of names such as:

```
John doe
Jane doe
Alvin a-chipmunk
Etc
```

I want it to be in all lower cast and skip the - in the last name, as well as if therw is a user like john and jane add a 1, 2, 3 etc to the end of their name.

I know the simple part of combining the name would look like:

```
=Lower(Left(concatenate([@[first name]],1),[@[last name]])
```

I'm just not sure about the searching through the last name and adding the 1,2,3... any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: For the "-" why not consider substitute() ?

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to illustrate in a 2-step process. There might be a way to combine to a single step.

**Step 1:** Create a helper column which creates a starting point for a username. This will substitute a hyphen with nothing and force all to lowercase.

```
C2 formula: =LOWER(CONCAT(LEFT(A2,1),SUBSTITUTE(B2,"-","")))
```

**Step 2:** Count the number of times that helper name appears from row-2 to current row. This will suffix the helper name with that number of times.

```
D2 formula: =CONCAT(C2,COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2))
```

As you can see, every username has a number suffix. If you don't want this, then an alt_username formula could look like this, which only adds a number if that helper name appears more than once.

```
E2 formula: =IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C2)=1,C2,CONCAT(C2,COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)))
```

[image]